# How do i get the payment method token in braintree GRANT API php

Tags: php, payment-gateway, braintree, braintree-sandbox

I am using braintree grant api to have access of client transaction. I am going through all the documentation and followed the example and have oAuth ready from my side.

this is my oAuth.php

```
$gateway = new Braintree_Gateway([
   'clientId'=>'client_id',
   'clientSecret' => 'client_secret'
]);
```

with the help of this, I created the connect with braintree button. Once authorized by the receiver, I get a code which I used to created access token.

```
$result = $gateway->oauth()->createTokenFromCode([
    'code' => $code
]);
```

In the $result variable I get an access token. Now as per the document, I need to generate Nonce and provide that nonce to receiver.

Code is given in the example

```
$grantResult = $gateway->paymentMethod()->grant(
   'the_payment_method_token',
   ['allowVaulting' => false, 'includeBillingPostalCode' => true]
);
$nonceToSendToRecipient = $grantResult->paymentMethodNonce->nonce;
```

Document is suggesting that i will get the_payment_method_token from the vault.

1: But Do i need to go to vault and manually copy paste the token OR is there any way I can get the token from the code dynamically.

2: How do I give only those nonce which are particular for receiver? My braintree account has many receiver connected and I don't want to share all the transaction details with them.

Please help!!

Comment: 1: You can run a [Customer::search()](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/customer/search/php) and then iterate through the returned object for the paymentMethodTokens

2: You can limit the [$scope](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/oauth/connect-urls/php#scope) that a recipient can access.

_Disclaimer: I work for Braintree. Please contact support@braintreepayments.com for further assistance_

Comment: Even for customer search, you need customer Id, how would I get that... Like I have multiple customer and it's dynamic so I will have to first find out customer id

Comment: You can search for customers that were created during a [certain time period.](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/customer/search#created-at)